# Set Property on a Covariant Interface

Tags: c#, covariance

I have the following covariant interface:

```
public interface IHierarchical<out T> where T : IHierarchical<T> {
    T Parent { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}
```

I then have the following interfaces which derive from the interface above:

```
public interface ISiteMapNode<T> : ISiteMapNode where T : ISiteMapNode<T> { }

public interface ISiteMapNode : IHierarchical<ISiteMapNode> {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I have the following implementation:

```
public class SiteMapNode : ISiteMapNode<SiteMapNode> {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ISiteMapNode Parent { get; }
    public IEnumerable<ISiteMapNode> Children { get; }
}
```

Now I have a method which takes an argument of type ISiteMapNode and tries to set the Parent property. Obviously this won't work as the Parent property is readonly. I had to remove set to make the IHierachical interface covariant. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot.

You can think of the `out` keyword before a type argument as saying that the declared interface will only return (or *output*) values of the specified type. This is analogous to the `in` keyword saying that the declared interface will only accept values of the specified type as *input*.

`out` = values are ONLY going out
`in` = values are ONLY going in

Covariant type parameter:

```
interface IHierarchical<out T>
{
    T Parent
    {
        get; // OK -- it's going out
        set; // ERROR
    }
}
```

Contravariant type parameter:

```
interface IHierarchical<in T> 
{
    T Parent
    {
        get; // ERROR
        set; // OK -- it's going in
    }
}
```

Invariant type parameter: (normal)

```
interface IHierarchical<T> 
{
    T Parent
    {
        get; // OK
        set; // OK
    }
}
```

One alternative could be to split the interface into a covariant and a contravariant subinterface. Something like this:

```
interface IHierarchical<T> : IHierarchicalIn<T>, IHierarchicalOut<T>
{
}

interface IHierarchicalIn<in T>
{
    T Parent { set; }
}

interface IHierarchicalOut<out T>
{
    T Parent { get; }
}

class Node : IHierarchical<Node>
{
    public Node Parent
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

I don't really see a use for that though.

Comment: Thanks I've added another Parent property on my class and then added a method called SetParent against the ISiteMapNode interface. This seems to be doing this job. This has opened up another issue but I'll create a different question. Thanks again.