# c# generics Property<string> in Dictionary<string, Property<object>>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, casting

I have a class with a generic type:

```
Property<T>
```

I want to add Property objects to a dictionary but I fail to do so:

```
var prop1 = new Property<string>("hello");
var prop2 = new Property<bool>(false);

var props = new Dictionary<string, Property<object>>();
props.Add("prop1",prop1); <-- this does not compile
props.Add("prop2",prop2);
```

I get:

```
cannot convert from 'Core.Property<string>' to type 'Core.Property<object>'
```

In java I would use

```
Map<String, Property<?>> props = new HashMap<String, Property<?>>();
```

That would take Property<String> and Property<Boolean>...

How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile - you wouldn't get an *exception*. It would help us help you if you could provide a [mcve]. It's possible that a non-generic base class or interface is the way to go here.

Comment: You are using `Property` as a method, shouldn't you be doing `var prop1 = new Property<...`?

Comment: Yacoub Massad, Jon Skeet: sorry, this was reduced code. I adjusted it.

Comment: It's still not a complete example though. You're still trying to add *just a value* to a dictionary, for example...

Comment: adjusted that. I hope the sample now illustrates the issue. The real code is much more complex.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the values after extracting them from the dictionary?  You won't know what the type of the property is so you're going to have to resort to reflection or `dynamic`.  I suspect there's a better way to solve the _real_ problem without shoehorning values into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Covariant here. if you are not familiar with Covariance and Contravariance in Generics I suggest you to read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx which describes them in details. So in order to work with you I suggest that you should only change your class to interface like that `Property<out T> to IProperty<out T>`
 and give it a try. tell me if it works with you. 
happy Coding.

Comment: Classes can't be covariant; only interfaces (and delegates) can, and only under certain circumstances.

Comment: Yes, you are right, So I suggest that he should change Property class to IProperty interface, and try using Covariant.

Comment: If the property class represents a mutable property then it's not going to be possible to make it covariant.  Also, as dustmouse points out, covariance won't work for value-type type arguments, such as `bool`.

Comment: Yes you are right. He should wrap his bool value to a class so covariant is going to work in that way.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve this in C#?

You *might* be able to define a covariant interface that `Property<T>` implements, but the interface can only contain methods and properties that *output* `T` - it cannot have a method or property setter that accepts `T` (or any derivative) as in input.  Even then, your vale type would be something like `IProperty<object>`, so you'd have no clue at compile-time what the underlying type of any of the values are.

If that's not possible then the only way is to switch the value type of your dictionary to `object` or `dynamic` and defer all type-checking to runtime (either through reflection or dynamic binding, respectfully).

Comment: This wouldn't even work for the basic scenario outlined because generic variance is not supported over value types.

Answer (score 0):

You could *almost* accomplish this with a **covariant interface**, but it *wouldn't work* with the bool property because it is a primitive.

You could set up your interface as follows:

```
public interface IProperty<out T> {
    T GetValue();
}

public class Property<T> : IProperty<T> {
    private T value;

    public Property(T value) { this.value = value; }

    public T GetValue() { return this.value; }
}
```

For the string property, your dictionary would look like this:

```
...
IProperty<string> prop1 = new Property<string>("hello");
var props = new Dictionary<string, IProperty<object>>();
props.Add("Test1", prop1); 
...
```

Comment: The GetValue() function works fine, but why can't I add a Set(T value) to the IProperty interface? I get "Invalid variance..."

Comment: It is due, to that covariant can be used only in output such as return value. Input such as method parameters can only be contravariant (declared by in keyword). You cannot declare type parameter as covariant and also contravariant.

Comment: @mvermand - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276231/set-property-on-a-covariant-interface

Comment: @dustmouse I stand corrected.  You'd have to declare the value as `Proerty<object>`.  I thought it would box it but apparently it won't.

Answer (score 0):

When you are initializing a Dictionary, you need to pass two parameters Key and Value. In your example I clearly see the Value that you want to add

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, Property<object>>(); //correct
props.Add(prop1);//where is the Key??
```

but where is the Key?